# Power BI dynamic filtering according to user account

Tags: reporting, business-intelligence, powerbi, microsoft-reporting

I want to develop indicators using Microsoft Power BI.

I have a Datawarehouse on SQL Server and I directly query from the DW.

I would like to display different information according to the user accessing the report. 
I didn't find a way on how I can dynamically filter the data according to the user account.

Is it possible?
If not, then what are the possible solutions to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is Row-Level Security and it is out with Sql server 2016 and Azure Sql DB, check here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn765131.aspx

I too have been looking for a similar solution to the same problem, I am using Azure SQL DW and I have been told the Row-Level Security will be coming to AzureSQLDW with GA, but not sure of the date on that.

So back to your question as far as I know the only possible solutions would be to use Sql 2016 Row-Level Security or you can also use SSAS in front of your data warehouse.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, even if I think I understand how to give some access at the DB level, I don't understand how the DB will know which user is connected. Because tell me if I'm wrong, I am using DirectQuery, and only the creator configure the directquery and the credentials. So it will display the same data no matter the user account on PowerBI is, or am I missing something?

Comment: I have not yet implemented this myself, however from what I understand the direct query would pass along the logged in user credentials when executing the query against the database or ssas.

Comment: I have implemented the same in PBI, using both import data and direct query, my data source is SSAS. Power BI will get user details from logged in user information, which will be passed on inherently along with the query to data source. you will have to implement row level security on SSAS database to achieve this.

Comment: NB Row-level security has recently been added to Azure SQL Data Warehouse.  See [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/row-level-security-is-now-supported-for-azure-sql-data-warehouse/) for more details.